# Changing offset from child processes

Tags: c, file-descriptor

Let say that I have a parent process, and then create some number of child processes in order to read from the same file.

1. when each process read from the file descriptor, is the offset been changed between all his sibling's processes?
2. and so, is it possible that each process will read a unique line, or that  without synchronized  the app , each process will read the same lines like his siblings?

   ```
   id = fork();

   if (id < 0)
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

   if (pipe(fd) == -1)
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

   switch (id) {
   case 0:
       //child process
       readFromFile(filename);
       exit(0);
       break;
   default:
       //Parent process doing something..
       break;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

On a POSIX system, file descriptors inherited by a child process through a `fork` call refer to the same file descriptor in a *system-wide* table.  Here's a relevant quotation from the Linux manual page for open(2):

> The term open file description is the one used by POSIX to refer to
>   the entries in the system-wide table of open files...
>   When a file descriptor is duplicated (using dup(2) or similar), the
>   duplicate refers to the same open file description as the original
>   file descriptor, and the two file descriptors consequently share the
>   file offset and file status flags.  Such sharing can also occur
>   between processes: a child process created via fork(2) inherits
>   duplicates of its parent's file descriptors, and those duplicates
>   refer to the same open file descriptions.

This means that the parent and child share the same information on file offset, and reads in one will change the offset seen by all other processes.  If processes read in parallel without `lseek`ing between reads, no two processes will read the same data.

You can see this in action in the following test program, which prints the first 20 characters of the file given in the command line.  (If position information wasn't shared, it would print the first 10 characters twice).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

char buffer[256];

int
main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    fork();
    read(fd, buffer, 10);
    write(1, buffer, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

**HOWEVER**, and this is a huge "however", this applies only to the low-level system call interface for reading files:  `open(2)`, `read(2)`, etc.  If you are using a higher-level buffered interface, like `fgets` and other functions in `stdio.h`, things get complicated.  When the processes are forked, even though they inherit copies of file descriptors that point to single system-wide, shared structures of file information in the kernel, they also inherit *separate* copies of user-space buffering information that's used by `stdio.h` calls, and this buffering information includes its own offsets (and buffers, obviously), which aren't synchronized between processes.

Answer (score 0):

> and so, is it possible that each process will read a unique line

As K. A. Buhr [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43708731/6372809), the processes will read different parts of the file, as a read from one will update the position on the other.

But if you're reading lines, you're in for trouble.

Unless you know the lengths of the lines in advance (i.e. they have a fixed length), you'll likely read partial lines, leaving the other process to possibly read the other part. To work around that, you'd need to either read one character at a time, or seek back to a line boundary after reading. Both of those will be subject to race conditions: the other process might read between your reads, or between your read and the seek.